# How to multiply the Column Vector and Row Vector from two Matrices without Loop?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have a question about how to multiply the **column vector** in matrix `A` with the **row vector** in its transpose `A.T`. Could you mind giving me some hints? Thank you!

- Suppose we have a (3x3) matrix `A` as follows.
- We want to multiply the **column** vector in `A` with the **row** vector in `A.T` (e.g. the red one). The result is a (3x3) **matrix**.
- While we have 3 row vectors, the final output shape should be (3x3x3).

**Question**: May I ask is there any way we can use matrix manipulation to achieve this? Because if we simply use `A @ A.T`, the result would be (3x3) **but not** (3x3x3).

(We can solve it by iterating every column of A. But can we solve it **without** for-loop? Thank you!)

[image]

```
# here is my solution with for-loop

import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,0,1],[2,10,0],[0,0,10]])

target = []
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    
    a = A[:,i].reshape(A.shape[0],1)
    tem = a@a.T
    target.append(tem)

print(np.array(target).shape)
```

Comment: `@` works if the `i`, batch dimension is first of 3. Read `matmul` docs.  `einsum` also has a lot of expressive power.

Comment: You may want  `swapaxes` or `transpose` rather than `reshape`

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, I figured it out with your instruction! I just need to do the reshape with `B1 = A.reshape(3,3,1)` and `B2 = A.reshape(3,1,3) `. Then `(B1@B2)` is what I need. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out this question. We just need the following two simple steps:

- Reshape the matrix to get one more axis for broadcasting:

  - `B1 = A.reshape(3,3,1)`
  - `B2 = A.reshape(3,1,3)`
- Then use the Dot/Mutual Product.

  - `B1@B2` is what we want.

(Huge respect to @hpaulj for his suggestions! Thanks)